# Universal login page appearence changed after I integrated server part

Tags: angular, nestjs, auth0

I just finished two tutorials related to [SPA Angular authentication](https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/angular/basic-authentication) and [NestJS API set-up](https://developer.auth0.com/resources/code-samples/api/nestjs/basic-authorization) and integration.

After I finished most of the Angular application configuration tutorial, the universal login page used to look like this one:
[image]
I configured it at the beginning and it appears on the Branding>Universal Login page of my tenant.

However, after I finished the tutorial for API configuration and integrated it with my client side. The universal login page changed its appearance to this:
[image]

How can I revert the appearance of the universal login page to what it looked like before API integration? And what's the cause of this behavior?